# gridview button field

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with a buttonfield. I want to update a table in my database and change the button image on button click. What is best event for that where i can access the row index as well?
I have tried using the RowCommand event but cant access the row index from that event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this code - based on `CommandArgument`

```
void GridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.CommandName=="Test")
    {
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
      GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.Rows[index];
    }
  }
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `asp:ButtonField` use `asp:TemplateField` and an `asp:Button` inside that. Set a `CommandName` say, **MyCommand**. Now inside the `RowCommand` event, do this

```
var clickedRow = (GridViewRow)((Button)sender).NamingContainer;
var clickedIndex = clickedRow.RowIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked the docs here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

If you look at the "Note" section (below for convenience) you should be able to get the RowIndex from the CommandArguement property:

> Note To determine the index of the row that raised the event, use the
>   CommandArgument property of the event argument that is passed to the
>   event. The ButtonField class automatically populates the
>   CommandArgument property with the appropriate index value. For other
>   command buttons, you must manually set the CommandArgument property of
>   the command button. For example, you can set the CommandArgument to
>   <%# Container.DataItemIndex %> when the GridView control has no paging
>   enabled.